# Resizing Window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've tried searching at why I can't get the content to stay centered as I resize the window larger but not quite understanding what I'm doing wrong.

From what I understand setting a weight to columnconfigure and rowconfigure will scale how much the content expands with the window but currently the enlarging the window keeps the content in the top left, can someone please help me understand where I'm going wrong?

```
def calculate():
    try:
        numValue = 100*float(num.get())/8
        num.set(str("%.2f"%numValue))
    except ValueError:
        num.set("Please enter a positive integer")
        pass

num = StringVar()

num_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=ozone)
num_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
num_entry.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
num_entry.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Number:").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=num).grid(column=2, row=7, sticky=(S))
ttk.Button(mainframe, width=20, text="Calculate Number", command=calculate).grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=W)


for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` for your frame and root, not for entry and other widgets. You already put your widgets in frame, so don't use `sticky`.

```
(...)

mainframe = Frame(root, width=500, height=500, background='green')
mainframe.grid(row=0, column=0)
mainframe.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

num_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable='ozone')
num_entry.grid(column=2, row=1)
# num_entry.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) not like this
# num_entry.columnconfigure(0, weight=2)
(...)
```